# Logout redirectTo not redirecting correctly

Tags: react-admin

I have a custom AuthProvider in react-admin
I am using the checkAuth function and the logic seems to be running correctly:

```html
checkAuth: () => {
    if(localStorage.getItem("userprofile")) {
      return Promise.resolve()
    } else {
      return Promise.reject({ redirectTo: '/login', message: 'login.required' })
    }
  }
```

The issue is that the resulting routed url seems to be defaulting to a specific resource. After the redirectTo call the browser redirects to: http://localhost:3001/login#/clients
instead of the expected http://localhost:3001/login

Is there some default route setting of some logic reason for this?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: You code seems correct, this is not enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I use react-admin 3.8.5 and to change this behavior I had to use customSagas:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customsagas

```
logoutSaga.js

import { UNREGISTER_RESOURCE } from 'react-admin'
import { replace } from 'connected-react-router'
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* logoutMonitor(action) {
  try {
    if (action.payload === 'your resource name') {
      yield put(replace({pathname: '/login', state: {nextPathname: '/'}})) // Changing the route for the next entrance!
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn('logoutSaga:', error)
  }
}

function* logoutSaga() {
  yield takeEvery([UNREGISTER_RESOURCE], logoutMonitor)
}

export default logoutSaga
```